# Realistic jazzy sound with VST

Tags: jazz, instruments, orchestra, daw, vst

I've been quite impressed with the orchestral sound of Nina Simone's "I put a spell on you". The part which interested me can be heard at first 17 seconds. So is it possible to simulate such warm and sensual sound like I described with VST? What instruments combination is used to record this? 
And how can I achieve at least a similar sound with DAW? I'm sorry for newbie questions :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get close.   I'd be interested to see what you think of this.  I'm sure it could be done better, but the frightening thing is how quick and easy it was to throw together this score in Sibelius and play it (with very little tweaking) using NotePerformer - a definitely budget-priced sound set.  [HERE'S](http://www.laurencepayne.co.uk/share/I%20put%20a%20spell.mp3) the sound file.

[image]

Comment: Thanks. This is exactly what I looked for. I'll work on it :)